# dynamic variable name based on multiple for loop

Tags: shell-script, for

I'm trying to create a dynamic name variables with the help of multiple for loop but the output says command not found.

- file `marklist_theory.txt`

  ```
  student1 10
  student2 20
  ```
- file `marklist_practical.txt`

  ```
  student1 20
  student2 20
  ```

I want output as

```
marks_student1_theory=10
```

and

```
marks_student1_practical=20
```

I tried this as below but it didn't work saying command not found due to multiple dynamic variables like `marks_student1_theory` & `marks_student1_practical` and wondering if anyone can assist me on it.

```
for i in {"student1","student2"}
do
  for j in {"theory","practical"}
  do
    marks_[$i]_[$j]=$(cat marklist_$j.txt |grep $i | tr -d '$i [:space:]'
  done
done
```

ARthur

Comment: Welcome to the site. May I recommend using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone program in many Linux distributions, to check your script for syntax errors etc.? I do find multiple issues with it which may be masking the underlying problem ...

Comment: How do you intend to use these variables later? What is the overall task that you're trying to solve? Is it to output a summary or average for each student?

Comment: That's not output you're trying to do here, that's an assignment. You should use associative arrays for stuff like that (`declare -A array` in Bash)